# How To use Datasource from Multiple Table to GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

excuse me, I want make layout like this:
[image: layout]

And the database stucture is like this:
[image: db]
I want use select query to load data from 2 tables and show the data to the gridview..
so far, I found tutorials at internet but using single table..
Please give me suggestion...

Comment: You have to read about joins.

Answer (score 2):

You should try something like this.

```
 string query = @"SELECT * FROM Sales_so
  Inner join Com_customer on COM_Customer.Com_customer_id = Sales_SO.Com_customer_Id";
 Connection con = new Connection();
 SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

 SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();
 dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
 dataGridView1.ReadOnly = true; 
 dataGridView.DataSource = ds.tables[0];
```

Answer (score 2):

Write query which Joins 3 tables, put the results in dataSet after that set this dataSet for DataSource of the grid.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
cmd.ConnectionString = "your connection";
cmd.CommandText = @"
SELECT 
    so.* -- WRITE Here columns which you need from the tables. 
FROM
    SALES_SO so
INNER JOIN
     SALES_SO_LITEM soItem ON soItem.SALES_SO_ID = so.SALES_SO_ID
INNER JOIN
     COM_CUSTOMER cus ON cus.COM_CUSTOMER_ID = so.COM_CUSTOMER_ID
";

DataSet resultDst = new DataSet();
using (SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd))
{
    adapter.Fill(resultDst, defaultTable);

}

grid.DataSource = resultDst.Tables[0];
grid.DataBind();
```

You need somethig like this

Comment: @irhabymailed4u you are welcome, good luck with your project. You can accept the answer if helped you.