# How can i add another column from different table in datagridview?

Tags: c#, sql

this is my table structure

[image]

it really works great on my current app which is look like this

[image]

as u can see whatever i click tarif_ismi on bottom datagridview the other DGV show me what's inside the selection.

what i want to do is i want to show user name not ID on top DGV

name should be  "Malzeme_İsmi" on depo where depo.ID=Malzemeler.ID how can i achieve this ? (english is not my native language so sorry for that )

edit:if i add this code top DGV will be filled all ingredients so i can no longer click my recipe(which is bottom dgv) and top dgv will not show what's include that recipe

```
 string query = @"SELECT Malzemeler.ID, Malzemeler.Tarif_ID, Malzemeler.Malzeme_Adet, Malzemeler.Malzeme_Gram, Depo.Malzeme_İsmi FROM  Malzemeler INNER JOIN
                     Depo ON Malzemeler.ID = Depo.ID";
       
        SqlDataAdapter dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(query, con);

        SqlCommandBuilder commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
        dataGridView2.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Edit:

i changed my dataset query with inner join

```
SELECT        Malzemeler.ID, Malzemeler.Tarif_ID, Malzemeler.Malzeme_Adet, Malzemeler.Malzeme_Gram, Depo.Malzeme_İsmi FROM       Malzemeler INNER JOIN
                     Depo ON Malzemeler.ID = Depo.ID
```

and all good

Comment: You need to use joins and get the required columns and bind to the Grid DataSource

Comment: i'm using datasource bound for the datagridviews can i do that without destroy that bound ? i'm newbie sorry if this sound stupid

Comment: See this Question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26378716/how-to-use-datasource-from-multiple-table-to-gridview

Comment: What is the datasource/binding for the DGV?

Comment: @jdweng i just use little box on top of DGV which say add dataset to table i select FKMalzemelerTarifler

Comment: Then you need to modify your dataset.  Are you using Entity or SQL Client?  Your Command Text SQL query needs to be modified.

Comment: @jdweng i'm using sql client i'll search for dataset modify right now

Comment: Do you want a second JOIN in your query? Do you want a WHERE in your query? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: @jdweng i found the solution thanks for u jdweng i'll edit my question so other will find too